# EMR Pyspark job, how to import python libraries in s3

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

We have a main job, let's call it main.py,

in the main.py job, we have other python libraries that is stored in s3. call it test1.py, test2.py

when I am submitting to the spark to run the main.py but it can not pick up test1.py and test2.py. in s3.

How to configure so that it can pick up test1.py and test2.py?

Answer (score 2):

If you have right permissions to access the s3 bucket,you can include them in `spark-submit` command with `--py-files` like below

```
spark-submit --py-files s3a://bucket/you-folder/test1.py,s3a://bucket/you-folder/test2.py main.py
```

Also, you can use copy step that downloads your file to emr node.

Comment: Note: even if the python files are in completely different paths inside S3, they will be imported in the same directory inside EMR: the home directory.